# Can we define an interface within an interface?

Tags: java, interface

I like to know can we define an interface within an interface.
like

```
interface abc {
    void show();
    public interface xyz {
        void read();
    }
}
```

This was question asked in interview. Any practical use of this.

Comment: 'Real-time' has a specific meaning in IT. and this isn't it. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, we can do it. The definition of the nested interface in java is as follows:

> A nested interface is any interface whose declaration occurs within the body of another class or interface. A top-level interface is an interface that is not a nested interface.

Refer [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html) for more.

Further ...

One reason could be that the outer interface has a method that takes a callback implementation as an argument. The nested interface is, in that case, the contract that the callback method must implement. I don't see a reason to declare that callback interface at the top level.

```
public interface Processor {
   void execute(NotificationListener listener);

    interface NotificationListener {
        void processingCompleted();
    }  
}
```

Another good reading at sun site about this topic is [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5283210)

In particular, notice that when you implement an interface, you are
not required to implement any
interfaces nested within.

Comment: @girinie I think you should accept HotTester's answer but for a real time use of it, look at Map and Map.Entry. The Map.Entry interface is part of the protocol for a Map (used when returning from Map.entrySet() ), hence it is part of the Map interface. (While writing this, HotTester added similar info to the answer, +1)

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted. Your last link is broken.

Comment: Well, one should add, that with kotlin and Java 8 lambda's this concrete interface seems excessive and there is no need for the nested interface

Answer (score 12):

Sure.. Look at  SOURCE CODE for java.util.Map interface.  Map interface contains a nested Entry interface.

Interestingly, in the source code it simply says

```
interface Entry <K,V> {
  ..
}
```

but the javadoc says

```
public static interface Map.Entry<K,V>
```

I guess this is because nested interfaces  are implicitly "public static" even though the source code doesn't say that.  (But methods inside an interface are implicity public, and cannot be static,that is, only instance methods are permitted in interfaces).

-dbednar 2013-07-02

Comment: Good explanation. In Addition, I have never seen anyone dating his answer like you did here. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

You could have tested that for yourself and got a completely definitive, opinion-free, risk-free answer in about 30 seconds.

Waiting possibly forever for a possibly incorrect response on a forum is by comparison not a rational mode of enquiry.

Comment: +1 Such laziness on the part of question submitters isn't good for anyone.

Comment: +1 It reminds me of this article: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: -1, You Squidwards, a good answer not only says "yes" or "no", but also includes more specific information, like pros and cons, use cases and other stuff, that could be obtained by experienced person. Even this question needs a caveat, see the accepted answer.

Comment: @Bagzerg What caveat?  I see no caveat there. And how exactly can you get more specific than 'yes'? That's what he asked for. Not 'pros and cons, use cases ...'. A good answer should answer the question that was actually asked, not waffle on irrelevantly. And who or what is 'You Squidwards'?

Comment: @DmitryGryazin Agree with you. Maybe the person who asked this question only interested in yes/no, but others could still discuss pros, cons, use cases, implementation details, etc., and could learn much interesting things from discussion.

Comment: @Endle_Zhenbo What they could all learn is to try it for themselves instead of wasting time, for the reasons stated in the answer. The only 'pro' is that the JLS permits it; for the same reason there is no 'con'; similarly there are no 'implementation details' to discuss. You seem to be just asking for the same kind of irrational waffle I am arguing against here.

Answer (score 2):

We are using it in our application,
Interface inside interface, using this basically for being functionality specific constants,
so that accidentally no other will create new constants somewhere else in the project, related to this Service1.

example Code:

```
Public interface Service1{

  public interface ServiceInter1{

   public Interface In{
    Declare your own constants
   }

   public Interface Out{
      Declare your own constants
   }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, we can define.

Inside Map interface define Entry as like below.
public interface Map {

```
/**
 * Map.Entry is a key/value mapping which is contained in a Map.
 */
public static interface Entry<K, V> {
    .....some loigic
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real use of this is to simplify a complex system by providing a Facade interface. - Check for the Facade design pattern.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern