# Nested Interfaces in java

Tags: java, interface, nested

I am using an interface for "Flags" in a class. Lets call it

```
public interface Flags
```

I want to be able to implement the Flags interface with an object and have it inherit all the sub flags that I put in it. Example

```
public interface Flags{
    static int flag1 = 0;

    public interface Size{
        public static int big = 1;
        public static int small = 2;

    public interface Direction{
        public static int left = 3;
        public static int right = 4;
```

So what I want is to have object Foo implement the Flags class

```
public class Foo implements Flags{}
```

and have access to all the sub flags (i.e. left, right, big, small, flag1).

But I also want it so that I can have Foo1 implement Size and only have access to the Size flags

```
public class Foo1 implements Flags.Size{}
```

I found this [Can we define an interface within an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332158/can-we-define-an-interface-within-an-interface) which shows that nested interfaces are possible but I am not sure how to do this in the manner I am looking for.

I have tried simply doing what I am looking for and it becomes a massive pain.
What I mean, is that if I wanted Foo to access flag big, I would have to do the following

```
public class Foo implements Flags{
    final int size = Size.big;
}
```

This is far from ideal. I would much prefer to do the following

```
public class Foo implements Flags{
    final int size = big;
}
```

Comment: You may be mixing up the notion of an interface with the notion of a class. An interface promises a certain behavior, and so anything that implements it must define that behavior. But you're currently trying to define fields, a feature of classes. But, you can nest classes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you not using Enums for this behavior?  You should be using an Enum for this, as these are static values [enum tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: I've not heard of the Enums object though that makes the most sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using interfaces to store constants is considered a bad practice (as pointed out by Joshua Bloch in Effective Java), they were simply not invented to serve such purpose. You should consider using static members of classes for this purpose or enums.

However, even if that was not a bad practice, such thing would not make any sense. If your class has access to the interface, it also has access to all its members.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you nesting the interfaces? Just declare the subinterfaces separetely, each one in its individual source file, and then make your `Flags` interface inherit from all of the subinterfaces:

```
public interface Flags extends Size, Direction {

    int flag1 = 0;
}
```

This would allow you to make your `Foo` class implement your `Flags` interface, thus inheriting all the fields, and would also allow you to make your `Foo1` class implement only the `Size` interface.

Note 1: it doesn't make any sense to declare interfaces members as `public`, since they are all public by default. And the same goes for `static` members: if a member is not a method, then it is automatically `static`.

Note 2: as others have indicated, using interfaces to store constants is considered bad practice. You should use enums instead. However, I'm not feeling as a purist today, and using enums wouldn't allow the behavior you're after, because enums can't be inherited.