# Nesting interfaces in AIDL

Tags: android, aidl

This is not duplicate of [interface within an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332158/can-we-define-an-interface-within-an-interface).
My question is specifically about [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) because the following doesn't seem to work in an AIDL file:

```
interface Foo {
    interface Bar {
        void doBar();
    }
    void doFoo();
}
```

The error I get is related to the `Bar` interface:

> 'interface' unexpected

If it is removed, then everything is fine.
**Anyway, above is valid java code, so why it doesn't work in AIDL?**

Comment: While AIDL closely resembles a Java `interface`, they are not the same. For example, with AIDL, you always have to have `import` statements for classes, even those in the same package as the AIDL itself. I am not terribly surprised that nested AIDL declarations are not supported. Move `Bar` into a separate AIDL file, and you should be fine.

Comment: I guess I don't have choice :) But thanks for the answer.